# applying a function to a list of data frames in R

Tags: r

I'd like to apply acast () to a list of data frames and return a new list of matrices.

```
list<-list(df1 = data.frame(vegspecies=c("vsp1", "vsp1", "vsp1", "vsp2", 
  "vsp2", "vsp2"), species=c("sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp2", "sp2", "sp2"), 
       her=c(0,0,1,0,3,2)), df2 = data.frame(vegspecies="", species="", her=""))
```

For a single data frame the function works fine.

```
acast(list$df1, vegspecies ~ species, fill=0)
```

Given that my list also contains empty data frames I used tryCatch() to ignore the error and retrieve a NULL element. This also seems to work fine.

```
tryCatch(acast(list$df2, vegspecies ~ species, fill=0), error=function(e) print(NULL))
```

But I am unable to apply this over the whole list of data frames. Ideally the output should be a list of matrices (those matrices will have different sizes). I think the error is the way how I create the empty list in the first place, but I couldn't fix it.

```
wideData <- list(df1 = matrix(), df2 = matrix())

for(i in 1:length(list)){wideData[i] <- tryCatch(acast(list[[i]], vegspecies ~ species, fill=0), error=function(e) print(NULL))}
```

Comment: what is S1 in your `list` ?

Comment: You forgot quotes in `"S1"` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This was indeed a mistake. I fixed the code and should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` of 'data.frame`s and apply the`acast` (assuming that 'df2' is also a similar dataset as 'df1' with same column names, types etc.)

```
res <- lapply(lst, function(x) acast(x, vegspecies ~ species, fill=0))
```

NOTE: It is better not to name a `list` object "list" (similarly a `vector` as "vector" or `data.frame` as "data.frame").  It can be any other name.

---

However, we can still use a single `acast` on a single data.frame by `rbind`ing the `lst` object with a 'id' column to identify the `list` element

```
library(data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(lst, idcol="grp")
dcast(dt, grp + vegspecies ~ species, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. Perfect! And yes you're completely right about not naming list a list, I just did this for the example, but lst is a better option.